# What is a word that means when people only contribute or speak when they have something of merit to say or add?

Tags: single-word-requests

Kelsey wanted to add to the conversation, but she wanted to be ________ and didn't want to add any noise to the conversation as the people talking in the debate were considered experts in the field. She didn't want to ask any ignorant or mis-informed questions.

Alex and Logan were having fun at the party speaking to the dj while he was playing music, but Logan didn't want to add any small talk or anecdotes that weren't funny into the conversation. She wanted to be ________

I only want people who are ________ on my Q&A website. Too many idiots contribute opinions when they don't know anything on the topic. They don't consider the factors from the opposing side, just their own.

Comment: I was going to blurt out *measured!* or *restrained!*, but then I read your last paragraph and thought better of it.

Comment: Two examples are *very* different.

Comment: They're not my wife's cousin, that's for sure!  "Taciturn" she was not, when she visited last week.

Comment: @HotLicks ??? You're making no sense. I could have used the word quiet or shy if I wanted to convey someone who was timid.

Comment: "Taciturn" does not mean "timid".

Comment: taciturn. adjective. (of a person) reserved or uncommunicative in speech; saying little. If I said a person was taciturn in a conversation about politics or relationships, what impression would that give in someone's head?

Comment: *Laconic* perhaps.

Comment: It would tell me that they know when to keep their mouth shut.

Comment: Sounds like she hopes to _sapient? Sagacious? Coherent?_

Answer (score 3):

**pertinent**

> : pertaining directly or significantly to the matter at hand; [**relevant**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/relevant) ([Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pertinent))

**apropos**

> fitting and [**to the point**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+the+point) ([American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/apropos))

**pungent** (or **poignant**)

> : being sharp and to the point
>   ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pungent))

Comment: Can a human be pertinent? Isn't it a word that's only used for things?

Answer (score 1):

People who contribute something useful are being **constructive**.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the word: compendious

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. However good your answer, you will need to prove its usefulness by citing at least one source (dictionary,etc.)  for verification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about "erudite"?

> Characterized by great knowledge; learned or scholarly - dictionary.com

It goes best with your third sentence, but to me sounds a little weird when coupled with "wanted to be".

Comment: Someone who is "erudite" can easily be excessively verbose.  William F. Buckley, eg, was the stereotype for "erudite", but he was by no means a man of few words.

Answer (score 0):

how about **cogent**?  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cogent)

> Appealing to the intellect or powers of reasoning; convincing: a
>   cogent argument